# Facebook login with accesstoken

Tags: facebook, javafx, webview, oauth, scribe

I have an accessToken from facebook and i am also able to fetch some data with the graph-api with signedRequest's. Means i have exchanged all tokens, codes etc. successfully. Also i can use graph-api to login.

But finally i only want to show the Startpage of a facebook-user which i know his name and i have access. Means its a friend of mine.

Example:
https://www.facebook.com/toni.maroni.501

would be the url which i want to display in a webview. How do i have to use the accessToken to authenticate my app (which has grant access to the public profil of this user) and show the above url without the user to login again into facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it turned out that i was searching at the wrong side. Finally all i needed/wanted to automatically relogin into a certain homepage after the application was closed. This has more to do with cookies than with the accessToken.

So solved with the help of cookie's.